# Html.Partial causing 404 in MVC Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

*I had previously asked a question about a 404 error being thrown but thanks to help from folks attempting to help me debug, I now have a more specific question to ask.*

I see the following error when I load any view that invokes `@Html.Partial`:

```
This localhost page can’t be found
```

In visual studio, I see `return View()` being hit.

Sample method from HomeController:

```
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult Welcome()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I'm using `Microsoft.AspNet.MVC` version `5.2.7` in case it's relevant.

Image of browser error:

[image]

RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

My directory:

[image]

Welcome.cshtml:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@{
Layout = null;
}    
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    @Html.Partial("_HeadPartial")
</head>
<body>
  <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

_HeadPartial:

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Any kind of partial reference:

```
 @Html.Partial("_AnalyticsPartial")
```

Gives me the above 404 error; removing the reference allows rendering to succeed.  My partials can be empty and still result in a 404.

Why is `@Html.Partial` causing this?

Answer (score 1):

The 404 is because it can't find your partial view. You just need to include the full path to the partial view, since it's in a different folder than the current view:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_HeadPartial")
```